# How do I automatically add the current datetime into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My goal: I have created a table named "catalog". Its purpose is to log in whatever is added/altered/deleted into the database.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog`(
  `cat_id` int(22) NOT NULL,
  `cat_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `datelog` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

and here is one example of my code after adding an inventory item. Note that 'invname' is the inputted name of the added item:

```
    $name = $_POST['invname'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO inventory (iname, amount) VALUES ('$name', '$amount')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if($result){
        $log = $name;
        $query = "INSERT INTO catalog (cat_desc, datelog) VALUES ( '$log', GETDATE() )";
        include 'alertsuccess.php';
    }
```

However, while the inventory is added unto the database, the catalog however does not appear whenever i check the database.

So my problem is: How do I make sure the catalog will get data from it?

Comment: `NOW()` is the MySQL function that will return the time\date, `GETDATE()` is for sql server

Comment: a reasonably fair assertion, but the risk of sql injection only happens if there is a way for users to input data.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you aren't getting any records in your catalog is you set the table up incorrectly.  If you don't specify a primary key (and you didn't) then when you do an update to the table, every field marked as NOT NULL must be provided.  You did not provide cat_id.  Either provide cat_id or change your table definition to add this:
PRIMARY KEY (ID).  This should be correct:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog`(
`cat_id` int(22) NOT NULL,
`cat_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`datelog` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cat_id)
);
```

or, more usefully, this will also fill in the timestamp for you:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog`(
`cat_id` int(22) NOT NULL,
`cat_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`datelog` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
PRIMARY KEY (cat_id)
);
```

Comment: I believe the PK should have `cat_id`? Also, did you want to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the cat_id?  I believe that the OP meant `int(11)`, instead of int(22), so that is not your addition, but then unsigned should be there too.

Comment: you're right.  I listed the table name by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NOW` instead of `GETDATE`.

Sources:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_getdate.asp

Answer (score 0):

You want to add AUTO_INCREMENT to cat_id to save you specifying a new id for every insertion

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog`(
  `cat_id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `datelog` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

You also should use NOW() instead of GETDATE() as MySQL doesn't support it